# Not getting correct results through list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

Let's say I have a string

```py
S='Let us start attending Stanford University Lectures'
```

Now if I want to have all the words that have an `'s'`  or `'S'` in them then the following list comprehension

```py
[x for x in S if 'S' or 's' in x])
```

I get the following

```py
['L', 'e', 't', ' ', 'u', 's', ' ', 's', 't', 'a', 'r', 't', ' ', 'a', 't', 't', 'e', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'S', 't', 'a', 'n', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'd', ' ', 'U', 'n', 'i', 'v', 'e', 'r', 's', 'i', 't', 'y', ' ', 'L', 'e', 'c', 't', 'u', 'r', 'e', 's']
```

but when I change the list comprehension to

```py
[x for x in S if 'S' in x])
```

I get the following

```py
['S']
```

Why am I getting incorrect results?

Comment: The second example *is* correct because you only ask for upper-case 'S'. The first example does not work as you expect, because `'S' or 's' in x` is always true.

Comment: You could have used `'S' in x or 's' in x` instead.

Comment: And if you want to get a list of *words*, you need to *split* the string into words first. Iterating over a string gives the individual characters, as you have seen.

Comment: its actually my mistake. Should have been using it on a list instead of a string.

Comment: Sounds like you only want a list of words with 's' in them:

my_str = 'Let us start attending Stanford University Lectures'
[x for x in my_str.split(' ') if 's' in x.lower()]